# Making custom pan in Google Jquery Map UI

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with the Google Map Api. So I used Jquery Google Map API to get the Map thing:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<button id='btnRight'>Right</button>
<button id='btnLeft'>Left</button>
<button id='btnUp'>Up</button>
<button id='btnDown'>Down</button>
.
.
.
.

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var map=$('#map_canvas').gmap({
            'center' : '57.7973333,12.0502107',
            'scrollwheel' : false,
            'zoom' : 10,
            'disableDefaultUI' : false
        });

        $('#btnRight').on('click',function(){
           //map should move to some pixels to right as it moves when we press right arrow 
           //in the navigation pan of the google map.I attached the image
        });

        //similar behaviour for left,down and up buttons
        //the work of these 4 buttons are similar to the 4 direction of the 
        //navigation pan that comes with the default ui of google maps

    });
</script>
```

[image]

I tried a lot to achieve this but with no success,please any one shed some light on this..please
thanks
Ankur

Comment: Haha we meet again, let's take a look ;)

Comment: Hahaha,@Slixx I achieved the zoomer thing,just stuck in navigation pane thing,, its pain I am literally starving for a single clue,of how to achieve it..please help me.... :(

Comment: I don't get it I think. When you press the > button of you google map, you moves to the right? Or do you want a specific position?

Comment: I want it to move a bit right the same way > thing do by default UI controls

Comment: And why not using the default control? Why would you write your own code for doing the same as the default?

Comment: Its the need of the project that the controls should match the theme of the project so that's why I want that, if I am able to do the moving thing (moving map to right on clicking my button), I will apply css rules to look alike the theme of the project
;(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13784/discussion-between-ankur20us-and-slixx)